# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in the program after building in jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have an exe file in a JavaFX project that I launch on a button click. Works fine in IDE, but if you build in jar it stops working and throws this error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: src\main\resources\com\application\exeServices\SetProcessWorkingSetSize.exe doesn't exist.

The project hierarchy:
[image]

The code I call exe

```
private void useCleaningService() {
    final String path = "src/main/resources/com/application/exeServices/SetProcessWorkingSetSize.exe";
    File file = new File(path);
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Preface:** This answer assumes you're using the "standard directory layout" of Maven/Gradle, based on the presence of `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources`.*

---

Files under `src/main/resources` are **resources**, not files. This means you have to access them using the resource-lookup API. For example:

```java
URL url = getClass().getResource("/com/application/exeServices/SetProcessWorkingSetSize.exe");
```

This will give you a URL pointing to your resource, and it will do this in an application-location-independent way. In other words, it finds the resource on the class-path/module-path. If you want to read the resource then you'd open an `InputStream` using `URL#openStream()` (or get an `InputStream` directly by using `Class#getResourceAsStream(String)`). Note that resources are read-only. Also, notice the above does not include `src/main/resources` in the path. That directory only exists in your project's development environment; it does not exist after deployment (nor does it exist in your *build* output).

As previously stated, resources are not files. This means you can't read them using the `File` API. This is especially true once you package your application into a JAR file or custom run-time image, because `File` has **no idea** how to read/reference the packaged resource.

But you have another problem. I strongly doubt Windows is capable of executing an executable file when it's packaged in a JAR file or custom run-time image. Just like the `File` API of Java, Windows has no idea how to read packaged *Java* resources. You'd have to extract the resource into a regular file, and then have Windows execute that file. For example:

```java
// uses java.nio.file.Path and java.nio.file.Files
private void useCleaningService() {
  Path exe = Path.of(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".app_name", "SetProcessWorkingSetSize.exe");
  try {
    if (Files.notExists(exe)) {
      try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/application/exeServices/SetProcessWorkingSetSize.exe")) {
        Files.createDirectories(exe.getParent());
        Files.copy(in, exe);
      }
    }
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(exe.toFile());
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

This will extract the executable file to an application-specific directory (replace `.app_name` with the whatever name you want for that directory) in the user's home directory (e.g., `C:\Users\<username>`). It will only perform the extraction if the target file doesn't already exist. This will prevent unnecessary work, but as currently implemented, it will also prevent replacing the executable with new *versions* of it (unless you change the name of the target file). So, depending on your needs, you might want to modify the code to extract the resource *once per application instance* (can be accomplished with a simple `boolean` flag).

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if file exists with `exists()` function, you obviously using wrong file path in your jar

Comment: I still can't figure out why this doesn't work in a jar file, the path should stay the same. Maybe my IDE is ignoring the file when building?